# Admin URL rewrite using .htaccess and Drupal

Tags: .htaccess, drupal

I have a drupal 10 application I'm writing and in the admin I have a module that basically creates a single div for a react application.

I have the following URL structure:
example.com/admin/content/my-app

I also have React Router setup, so when I click a link to /companies, my URL changes client-side to example.com/admin/content/my-app/companies

This works fine and the correct component loads, but whenever I hit refresh on the browser when I'm on /companies, I get page-not-found.  Obviously this is because a URL matching example.com/admin/content/my-app/companies doesn't exist.

In .NET world, I fixed this by adding a fallback URL in the MVC routes so that any requests to:
example.com/admin/content/my-app/* are always re-written to the react application root at example.com/admin/content/my-app

However, I've tried every which way to create such a rewrite rule in .htaccess for my drupal application, and I simply cannot make the rewrite work without ending up with a 404.

I'm guessing order of where I put it in the .htaccess matters, but I can't seem to find a place where it does.  Can anyone provide insight into how to handle this scenario?

Comment: I have the same problem with Nginx. When i access the page /demo i can walk trough app normally (/demo/component) and React router works fine... but when i hit reload i got 404 by drupal.